# sprite kit: verify if touch is inside a node

Tags: ios, ios7, touch, sprite-kit

I'm trying to figure out how to detect if I touch a node in sprite kit. I thought it was function like this in UIView:

```
[myView pointInside:point withEvent:nil];
```

But so far I can not have found an alternative to this. What I'm trying to accomplish is to know I have touch the sprite node in the screen.

I'll really appreciate if you can help me to I acomplish this

Here is what I have in my code. I'm adding animated node:

```
-(void)addMyNodeAnimated
{
    NSMutableArray *myNodeArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray *animatedFrames = [NSArray new];
    SKTextureAtlas *AnimatedAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"pc2"];
    int numImages = (int)AnimatedAtlas.textureNames.count;

    for (int i=1; i <= numImages; i++) {
        NSString *textureName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%d", @"pc2", i];
        SKTexture *temp = [AnimatedAtlas textureNamed:textureName];
        [myNodeArray addObject:temp];
    }
    animatedFrames = myNodeArray;

    SKTexture *temp = animatedFrames[0];
    SKSpriteNode *animationNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:temp];
    animationNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    animationNode.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    animationNode.name = @"AnimationNode";
    [self addChild:animationNode];

    [animationNode runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:
                                  [SKAction animateWithTextures:animatedFrames
                                                   timePerFrame:0.1f
                                                         resize:NO
                                                        restore:YES]] withKey:@"AnimationRuning"];

}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint _touchLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInNode:self];

     SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:_touchLocation];

    if (node != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"node name %@", node.name);
    }

}
```

When I touch the node in the screen the node returns null.

Any of know why is this?

Answer (score 4):

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"yourSpriteName"] && [node.name isEqualToString:@"yourEffectName"]) {
        //Whatever you want.
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work for me because I'm using ninja blade effect and only is detecting the node with the blade effect.

Comment: I have add my code where I'm adding the sprite node and I have not been able to detect when I touch the sprite. The node of the touch always returns null.